# Can a public class's super class be package private?

Tags: java

Is it legal to have 2 classes in the same package, where one class is a subclass of the other, where the subclass is public while the super class is package private?

eg:

```
package test;
class SuperClass {
    public void f(){}
}

package test;
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
}
```

1. Is it legal?
2. If so, are there any technical reasons (not opinion) why it should not be used?
3. Is this widely understood behavior?
4. Is this recommended? (opinion)

My testing shows that JavaDoc renders the docs for the sub class as if the super class did not exist. No mention of a super class. Public methods declared and implemented in the super class are shown as though they were declared in the sub class.

Java reflection API shows similar behavior: public methods declared and implemented in the super class return the sub class when `.getDeclaringClass()` is called on the `Method`. However, `subclass.getSuperclass()` does return the correct super class.

Additional classes and output:

```
package test;
public class InstanceOfChecker {
    public static boolean isInstanceOfSuperClass(Object o){
        return (o instanceof SuperClass);
    }
}

package otherpackage;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("f() declaring class: "
                + SubClass.class.getMethod("f").getDeclaringClass().getName());
        System.out.println("super class: "
                + SubClass.class.getSuperclass().getName());
        System.out.println("InstanceOfChecker returns: "
                + InstanceOfChecker.isInstanceOfSuperClass(new SubClass()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
f() declaring class: test.SubClass
super class: test.SuperClass
InstanceChecker returns: true
```

Comment: It sounds like you've already proved that it's legal.  As to whether it's a good idea, that's kind of opinion-based, but I'm sure you can think of use cases for it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem "compiles and runs" != "legal"

Comment: Really?  What would constitute an "illegal" (compiling and running) program in your vernacular?

Comment: Look, my opinion is - if you want to do it, and you think it's appropriate for your project, then go ahead and do it.  As far as I know, there are no "Java police" who will arrest you for writing illegal code.

Comment: If spec says "thou shalt not" but compiler/rt does not enforce the rule, then you could have illegal + compiling + running.

Comment: I can't think of any cases in Java where that happens.  It's the job of the compiler and the JVM to enforce the spec.  If they don't do that, it's a bug

Comment: make the super class "abstract", and that will be  better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Is it legal?

Yes

2. If so, are there any technical reasons (not opinion) why it should not be used?

No

3. Is this widely understood behavior?

I haven't seen it often but you can find it a couple of times within the JVM (but I don't remember right now, where I've seen this)

4. Is this recommended? (opinion)

I'm not aware that I have ever seen a recommendation or discouragement of this technique.

Concerning why you want to do this. You might want to create a library with public classes that share a lot of code. So you create an abstract class containing this code that you don't want to expose to make sure that you can do changes to this class without breaking code "out there". `protected` can't prevent that so you make the abstract class package visible. It forces you to put all subclasses into the same package but that's not a real problem in general.

Comment: Your last paragraph is exactly the use case in the code I am looking at.